# Offset and Stack Divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack two `div` elements on top of each other with the lower element offset from the first like this:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                        │
│  Hero Content                                          │
│                                                        │
│                                                        │
│                                                        │
│                                                        │
│                                                        │
│                                                        │
│                                                        │
│                                                        │
│  ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐   │
│  │                                                 │   │
│  │                                                 │   │
└──┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───┘
   │                                                 │
   │                Navigation Menu   (solid)        │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I got this to work with absolute and relative positioning, but the problem is that any content the follows is tucked under the lower/last element above since it's using absolute positioning. I've tried using some clearfix hacks online, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there anyway to push all elements below the bottom one so they appear in order? Or is there another way to accomplish this effect that I'm not thinking of?

Here's what I have:

```css
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-section {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 500px;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  Hero
  <div class="bottom-section">
    Nav Section
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Main Content
</div>
```

Comment: Give `.hero` a bottom margin at least as tall as `.bottom-section`'s height

Comment: @KunalTanwar your *"check this out"* has not much to do with the question problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use position: absolute, just add some negative margin to the "nav" Element and improve the markup by adding the hero's "body" Element:

```css
.hero-body {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
}

.hero-nav {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: -50px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-body">
    HERO
  </div>
  <div class="hero-nav">
    HERO Nav
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Main Content
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the rest of your content underneath in a div and put a margin-top the height of the whole hero + bottom section?

```css
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-section {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 500px;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20%);
}
   .content-container{
margin-top: 600px;
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  Hero
  <div class="bottom-section">
    Nav Section
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  Main Content
</div>
```